# Custom action to launch Msiexec during setup

Tags: c#, installation, action

I finished my software and I'm not able to find a correct way to create its setup.

I searched the web and here but I found only old post referring old visual studio versions.

As I know in VS 2013 community edition I have a limited Installshield plugin and I was able to download the Visual Studio Installer plugin too. To create a simple setup is relatively easy but I need to silent install  a small software during my setup. The software is Double Agent (an updated version of the Microsoft Agent) and the developer recommend to launch the setup in this way:

Simply run:

```
msiexec /i DoubleAgent_x86.msi /qb-!
```

during your setup (i think the best place should be the Commit event).

By the way it's not possible to launch .msi installer with an action and I really don't understand the best practice to create a custom action.

I read something about to create a class but most articles refer to Visual Studio 2008 or to Wix plugin. I'm searching a way to use Msiexec with Visual Studio Installer or installshield.

Edit: I found this solution and it works so good: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

It's in Italian but it's easy to translate to the original language (English) with the top right radio button. It's working perfectly with Visual Studio Setup plugin and VS Community edition 2013.

I have no code to post at this time because I built only their sample but I will post it asap with the usage of msiexec for the hidden installation.

I created a test winform project, I added the installer class with this code:

```js
        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);
            // Use ProcessStartInfo class
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = "/i DoubleAgent.msi /qb-!";

            try
            {
                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log error.
            }
        }
```

And I created the setup with Visual Studio installer. At the end of the main setup something start saying there is another installation but the double agent does not install.

Edit again: I have not Admin right to execute msiexec silently. I think because the Double Agent setup need admin rights. I don't want to use manifest to elevate privileges then I think the only solution is to show the DoubleAgent installer (also if in minimal output).

By the way I have this code working in form 1 Button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "/i DoubleAgent.msi /qn";

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("Finish");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

But the same code does not work during the installation process.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to work! One MSI setup cannot launch another MSI setup. When it says "another install is in progress" it is referring to your one that is already running. It's not about admin privilege - you cannot install another MSI from an installer custom action, no matter what that developer says.

In general this is what bootstrappers are for, to install prerequisites before installing the main MSI. That's why even VS setups let you generate a setup.exe to install prerequisites (many of which are MSI-based) before installing your MSI.

So you'll need to figure out a bootstrapper (don't know if InstallShield LE has one) that will install that MSI. There used to be a tool called Bootstrap Manifest Generator that you could use to tailor the setup.exe to install custom prerequisiyes like yours. Or you could use the bootstrapper from WiX to install that MSI then your MSI. Or you could just copy that MSI to the system and have your app install it the first time it is used.

Or maybe that agent software is available as merge modules, in which case you just add the merge modules to your MSI build.